# How to get this pointer to vtable

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm stuck on a problem that I think is quite simple, but I'm having trouble explaining this, I hope I'll be able to do it this time. I'm making a modding kit that will be able to dynamically reload assets in the game, the thing is many modders don't have the same version of the game for various reasons which means that I have to make my tool compatible with all of them, that's why I need to know the value of this pointer dynamically. Is it achievable without asm by catching it with the mov instruction? Or can I simply do something with the byte 05 CF BA C0 02 ?

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: [`this` is a prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) so you can't take its address.

Comment: I was talking about the one in red on the picture

Comment: What you have here is an RIP relative calculation (`lea rax,[rip+0x2c0bacf]`). If you can decode it, you can trivially get the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How did you get the 0x2c0bacf? Is it related to big Indian conversion or something ? Also I assume rip is the address of my dll ?

Comment: That value was observed from the last 4 instruction bytes, which store the 32-bit numeric constant in little endian byte order on x86/64.

Comment: `rip` is the address of the `lea` instruction itself (or maybe the next instruction after, I forget which).

Comment: Another thing you might be able to do is create an object with this vtable and then read the vtable from the object. Depending on how much the code changes, that could be more reliable (you'd need to be able to get an object or call a function that creates one)

Comment: You can also see the original form of RIP-relative things in IDA by turning on Explicit RIP-addressing in the Processor specific options, apparently.

Comment: Probably a typo, but if not, Big **Endian**.

Comment: Thank y'all for your answers, just one last thing, how am I supposed to decode the RIP relative, while the address of the vtable is located at 0x2D18080

Comment: The address loaded to RAX depends on RIP at the moment of executing `LEA RAX, [vtable]` which is `0x10C5B1` (address of the following instruction). When you add `0x2C0BACF`, it gives `0x02D18080`.

Comment: Wow ok I hate my Windows calculator so it’s trivial ! Thanks again

Comment: @BamBou - the displayed code bytes are in byte order, so offsets are in little endian. That means CF BA C0 02 => 02C0BACF.  If vtable is fixed at 0x2D18080, then you could patch the code to `mov eax, 0x2D18080`, `nop`, `nop` (assuming mov eax is 5 bytes).